# In IP, to what extent are the network addresses coordinates?

Tags: ip, network, osi

Routing of data relies on being able to reach the destination address. There are network addressing systems proposed where the addresses are coordinates, Vivaldi from MIT, for example. The routing in these network topologies has the advantage of knowing when a package gets closer to its destination. In the IP system most commonly used as layer 3 in the OSI model, is there any notion of location in how machines are addressed?

Vivaldi: A Decentralized Network Coordinate System,
http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/vivaldi:sigcomm/paper.pdf

Netsukuku,
http://netsukuku.freaknet.org/doc/main_doc/netsukuku.pdf

PIC: Practical Internet Coordinates for Distance Estimation, 
http://rowstron.azurewebsites.net/MS/PIC-ICDCS.pdf

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That depends very much on what you consider as dimensions.

IP uses a paradigm of *network part/prefix* + *host part* that could be regarded as dimensions. The network prefix is used to select the next-hop gateway and on the last hop, the host part is used to select the destination host.

If you visualize all networks on one axis and all hosts in each network on the other axis, that's a kind of coordinate system.

Of course, the division between network address and host part is flexible in IP, as defined by the subnet mask or prefix length - a very clever scheme. The prefix length usually varies along the path, from more general, aggregated routes from afar to more precise, refined routes when closing in towards the host.

For instance, your ISP may advertise the 123.45.0.0/16 route on the Internet. Behind the border, 123.45.64.0/18 indicates the datacenter with your server in it. Inside the datacenter, 123.45.67.0/24 addresses the subsection and 123.45.67.80/28 your allocated address range with your server finally at 123.45.67.89.

Obviously, the IP "coordinate system" is a purely logical one - it as no relation to the actual location. IP routers have to exchange, learn and update their routing tables to be able to route towards any IP address (and not away from it).

The papers you've linked to try to establish a geography-based coordinate system to simplify routing - however, the challenge would be to deploy a rigid scheme that never needs updating, which probably isn't possible in practice. Once people use tunneling (for various reasons) all purely geographical routing fails.

Comment: I put it to you that it is a coordinate system that maps to a geographical coordinate system / an actual location in the sense that (for most IP addresses) they belong to a physical device or devices that have a specific geographic location.  It is just that the paths between physical devices are more important than physical location when directing packets.

Comment: It *could be* a geographical coordinate system, but in practice, there is no relationship between addresses and location.  Consider two network addresses, 2.2.2.0/24 and 2.2.2.3/0/34.  They may be in the same building, or they may be half a world apart.  There is no geo relationship, and whatever relationship may be at the moment, it can change at any time.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be ideal to use topological addresses that actually address where packages should be transported. The word address itself means "ad" "direct", direct towards. It seems to me that ARPANET was designed without actually planning to scale to the size the internet is today, and that the exponential increase in price-performance of memory over the past 50 years has allowed the internet to compensate for a poorly designed network layer by using resource-expensive routing tables.

Comment: The simplest design from my PoV would be just longitude/latitude based addresses with a unique identifier as well (could be a public key, easily allowing machine-specific encryption as well. )

Comment: @johan *actually address where packages should be transported* - that's how IP routing works when used correctly. Of course, ARPANET wasn't intended for anything like the Internet we've got today. ARPANET and the early Internet were designed for a few thousand hosts. I wouldn't call it "poorly designed" though - it still runs today's Internet on an incredible increase of scale. If anyone actually had had a *much* better idea it'd have replaced the routing long ago. Have you thought about roaming users? VPN? But we're drifting off into opinion land...

Comment: It seems to me that the routing actually does not scale well. And, that an easy way to remove or reduce to near nothing the need for routing tables is geographical addresses. That could be an absolute fact, and the preference could be an opinion. As far as the question I had, I was interested in an answer (with consensus) on if there is a notion of coordinates in IPv4. Yours and Rons replies seem contradictory, I am simply interested in objective truth to avoid opinion land. Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on what your coordinates refer to. If you look at geographical location, I think we all agree the answer is no.  You can create a topology map of the Internet, and addresses may have coordinates in that system.

Comment: But you need to ask yourself what would be the purpose of a geographical system?  the papers you cite aim to improve performance, but latency is as much a function of of bandwidth as it is physical distance.

Comment: Just coordinates as coordinates, network topology-based addresses, including geographical coordinates, are ideal for routing, can allow for greedy routing, memoryless routing. http://cs.yale.edu/homes/ramki/hotnets.pdf. It seems like current IP addresses with subnets and supersets (and bitmasks/subnet masks that while humans can read a particular hierarchical level without need for & bit-operator can be useful for machines) could be organized into a hierarchical structure, analogous to Netsukuku, where greedy routing can be applied, but that it is not really done. But that is a bit of a guess.

Comment: *could be organized into a hierarchical structure* - yes, of course. But you can't rearrange/renumber the Internet at will. The main problem is the wasteful address allocation during the early years and the resulting address space fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

> In the IP system ... is there any notion of location in how machines are addressed?

In a word, no. An IP address is not a physical location. In fact, otherwise sequential /32's may be miles apart. For example, my DSL connection has a static /32. One might assume -- from Bellsouth's WHOIS records -- everyone in that netblock are in the same general region, but that's not necessarily the case, as the account for whom that address is assigned can be used to login on *any* DSL port in the network. (I have personally used my account on devices in 3 states spanning a region of over 1000 miles. And it literally takes seconds to logout in one place, login at another, and *poof* that address is now hundreds of miles from where it just was.)

The same sort of portability exists in data center ("cloud") networks. VXLAN can allow what appears to be a continuous layer-2 network to span buildings, countries, and even continents.

It's up to individual networks to adopt their own "address plan". That plan may, or may not, have some relationship to geography -- it's ultimately a personal preference.

Routing on the internet is done between *Autonomous Systems* using BGP. BGP's primary path selector is "AS path length" - how many AS will the packet have to traverse. Eg. 1-2-2-3 (4) is longer than 1-2-3 (3) -- 4 vs. 3. 1-4-3 is also 3 hops, so which is chosen in many cases comes down to local preference. (although BGP does have numerous selection criteria, because such "ties" come up often.) This does lead to internet traffic rarely following what might otherwise appear to be the most *geographically optimal* path.

Comment: not necessarily geographical coordinates, "virtual coordinates" is a term often used. just wonder to what extent the capacity of 32-bit addresses to represent locations in a network topology is actually used.